# C++ Classes Importance of Public and Private Domains

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and just recently learned about classes. When you define something in the private domain of a class, such as a class function, how exactly is it limited to that class? For example:

```
class Example {
    void dosomething(param1, param2);
};
```

Would that mean that you can't access the class function in the main function? If so, what's the point of doing that, wouldn't that mean you can't use it at all?

One final thing, I've always seen class attributes defined under the private section of the class. What would happen if you put it under public?

Comment: I suggest you find yourself either a C++ book or a OOP book and read up about the theory of Encapsulation

Comment: consider you go to a bank. They will not let you enter their safe and take money out, but instead you interact with an employee at a counter. Thats the difference between public interface and implementation details in a nutshell. If you run a bank you will understand why it is not a good idea to let any customer enter your safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would that mean that you can't access the class function in the main function?

Yes.

> If so, what's the point of doing that, wouldn't that mean you can't use it at all?

Of course you can use it. From within other functions of this class:

```
class Example {
    void dosomething(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << "dosomething(a=" << a << ",b=" << b <<")\n";

public:
    void callDoSomething(int b) {
        dosomething(13, b);
    }
};

//main
Example e;
e.callDoSomething(5);
```

> One final thing, I've always seen class attributes defined under the private section of the class. What would happen if you put it under public?

Nothing would happen. They would be visible to everyone (just like private vs. public functions) and anyone can access them.

In general, to keep encapsulation alright you want data members to be private, but it strongly depends on use case. I suggest getting some books on OOP and encapsulation to learn more about the topic.

Comment: i wouldn't call public members "bad practice" in general. Usually encapsulation is desired, but if not then there is no point in doing encapsulation only for the sake of encapsulation. Writing getters and setters that do nothing but make you feel like you do proper encapsulation are much worse practice than public members imho

Comment: @idclev463035818 I meant that the general consensus is that it's a bad practice (and some people would do anything to avoid public member, even writing getters and setters). I agree with you and Uncle Bob. Reformulated that part, hope it's clearer.